# Auto populating sharepoint date field on SP new form shows wrong year value

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have a date column called Today Date on one of the list forms. I am trying to auto-populate it and set it to current date when newform is opened. Its pulling current month and day value fine but not the accurate year value.

Below is the code I added on the new form.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var today = new Date();   
    var todayDay = today.getDate();   
    var todayMon = today.getMonth() + 1;   
    var todayYear = today.getYear();   
    today=todayMon + "/" + todayDay + "/" + todayYear;  
    $("input[title='Today Date']").val(today);
})
</script>
```

Below is what I see on the form.
[image]

Can anyone help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have used `today.getYear()` it correctly returns 119. You have to add 1900 to the result.

You can also use `today.getFullYear()` which should return 2019.